# calculate malus value of a urn

Tags: optimization, game-theory

In an urn, I can put 20 balls having a value from 1 to 7.

So I got Ni, with i $\in$ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], where Ni is the number of balls with a value i in the urn.

And $\sum_{i=1}^7 Ni = 20$

The game is played like this :

- At the first round I pick 3 balls randomly.
- Every round I Need to play the round's number in value of balls.
  (At the second round, I need to play one balls with a value of two, or two balls with a value of 1)
- The the balls used on a turn disapears
- Every round I pick one balls randomly
- If I dont do so there is a malus. The malus is counted like that :

malus = $(N_r - V_r ) * M_r$

$N_r$ = round's number

$V_r$ = Value played at this round

Mr = Malus coefficient of this round (there is one for all the round)
, $M_r$ $\ge$ 1

My goal, is to calculate this malus given the urn.

---

My method for this calcul go like this :

First round, I got two possibilities :

- I can play 1 ball of value 1 : 1 - $\binom{20-N1}{3}$
- I cant play : $\binom{20-N1}{3}$

Second round, I got 8 possibilities :

Turn 1, I played :

- I can play 1 ball of value 2
- I can play 2 ball of value 1
- I can play 1 ball of value 1
- I cant play

And same 4 possibilities if I dont played..

So every turn the calcul become harder..

If there is only 7 turn, it resul in :

2 * 4 * 7 * 12 * 19 * 30 * 45 = 17236800 possibilities to calculate

Is there a better way to do it ?

I tried to use the Law of total probability to find a series that I could sum, but I didnt suceeded in it.

( I also did a simulation before that, but I want the real result and not the result $\pm  \epsilon$

Tell me if you need more information.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Three questions: a) You call it a "malus", but if I understand correctly it can be both positive and negative. Don't you want to take the absolute value (or the square) of the difference of the round number and the value played? b) I don't understand how "I can't play" and the malus fit together. My understanding of the malus was that if you play something other than the round number, you get the malus -- but that's different from not being able to play. c) Are you trying to calculate the minimal malus upon optimal play? If not, what assumptions are you making about the player's choices?

Comment: a) the malus is only positive. ( I will add this information, thanks) 
b) The calcul of the malus is (Nr - Vr ) * Mr. in ths case where I cant play, Vr = 0, So the malus = Nr * Mr.
lets say its turn 3, the $M_3$ = 3, the malus will be 3*3 =9

Comment: c) I am trying to calculate the malus according to a urn. The player choices stand like this : 
- He try to play the max value ( = Nr ), he try with only one ball, if he cant with two ball etc.. 
- If he cant play Nr value, he try Nr-1 and so on. Thanks for the help

Comment: You edited the question to say that the malus coefficient is non-negative, whereas above you wrote that you'd add the information that the malus is positive. There are two discrepancies there.

Comment: Yes thanks, edited.